# Python requests.get and urllib.urlopen returning different HTML to browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, screen-scraping, urllib

I'm sure this is a super common question but I'm just trying to get an understanding of what's happening so I can get Learned.

**Problem**: Running urllib.urlopen and requests.get both return different HTML to what's returned in browser. I've disabled Javascript just in case it was going via AJAX or something, but the problem persists. I've also checked the Developer Tools for XHR calls or otherwise but have found nothing.

Python Code:

```
headers = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch',
'Accept-Language':'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6',
'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
'Connection':'keep-alive',
'Cookie':'tgaLiveAssistantVisible=false; ASP.NET_SessionId=c5wxbmboygytpn20gubpbh0o; .ASPXANONYMOUS=lLuVr11J1Tbq9zbQPk-ZpOFMQQ4gOlePIJpfGJwAnsFNV-1gUyvJpfb2ubnIPGZg8dQnlygyrKDj1KGf14vUehOx6Iwolslm0NZZkVbfdRvv9nBZhrmAiC-2MQijnBlmZPwinqBVVVrmBmVQavyOqUVzKWr8qapeBUO4nHWgzEy_1MqPx2njtCs0DvZ3IUdz0; __utmt=1; __utma=185625580.34928295.1483869478.1484065473.1484068673.4; __utmb=185625580.17.10.1484068673; __utmc=185625580; __utmz=185625580.1484065473.3.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)',
'Host':'training.gov.au',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
}
# Load the RTO page
r = urllib.urlopen('https://training.gov.au/Organisation/Details/45001')
# r = requests.get('https://training.gov.au/Organisation/Details/45001', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.read(),"html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Returns at the bottom of the HTML:

```
<div class="display-row">
<div class="display-label">ABN:</div>
<div class="display-field-no-width">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Whereas in the browser:

```
Request URL:http://training.gov.au/Organisation/Details/45001
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:117.53.170.212:80
```

Returns the HTML:

```
<div class="display-row">
<div class="display-label">ABN:</div>
<div class="display-field-no-width">
<a href="http://www.abr.business.gov.au/search.aspx?SearchText=90608470113"title="View organisation on ABN Lookup"rel="external">90 608 470 113
<span class="accessibilityOnly">(external link)</span>
<img src="/Content/images/openNewWindow.png" alt=""/>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Can someone please explain to me why this might be happening?

Comment: `requests.get(url).content` returns what you see in browser.

Comment: .content still returns:

<div class="display-row">
<div class="display-label">ABN:</div>
<div class="display-field-no-width">
</div></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use requests:

```
import requests

url = 'https://training.gov.au/Organisation/Details/45001'
r = requests.get(url).text
```

out:

```
<div class="display-row">
                <div class="display-label">ABN:</div>
                <div class="display-field-no-width">
                <a href="http://www.abr.business.gov.au/search.aspx?SearchText=90608470113"title="View organisation on ABN Lookup"rel="external">90 608 470 113
<span class="accessibilityOnly">(external link)</span>
<img src="/Content/images/openNewWindow.png" alt=""/>
</a>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is your output from browser or from python that you've run? For me using requests.get(url).text is still outputting the empty <div>s

Comment: @user2620825 from python

Comment: **url = 'https://training.gov.au/Organisation/Details/45001'
r = requests.get(url).text
print(repr(r))**

is giving me the ABN, but as soon as i add **soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"html.parser")
 print(soup)** I get my initial output

Comment: @user2620825  use lxml as parser.

Answer (score 0):

server might give you different responses depending on your browser type. If you wish to get the same response as your browser, you may have a look to selenium python bindings.